# Python e function with limit

Tags: python, math

Given the following sample of code:

```
import math
e = lambda x: (1+(1/x))**x
for x in range(1, 20):
    print(math.e > e(10**x))

True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
True
True
False
True
True
True
True
```

Why does this oscillation between True and False happen? Isn't that supposed to be always True?

```
import math
e = lambda x: (1+(1/x))**x
for x in range(1, 20):
    print(math.e > e(10**x))

True
...
True
```

Comment: @slothrop there are extra characters in the text that are being eaten by the markdown processing.

Comment: Round-off errors.  Just that simple.  `1/10` cannot be represented exactly in binary, so you get an approximation.  Sometimes the approximation is just a bit high, sometimes just a bit low.

Comment: Consider the case where x (in the for loop) is 19. Then the `e` function is trying to calculate (1+10^-19), and raise that to the power of 10^19. Clearly (1+10^-19) requires the equivalent of 20 decimal digits of precision to represent, but that's more precision that floating point numbers can achieve.

Comment: @Goku OP is calculating `e(10**x)` rather than `e(x)`. In other words the range of arguments is 10 to 10^19, rather than 1 to 19.

Comment: @Goku In exact math, `e(x)` would converge to `math.e` for large x. But in floating point math, we get precision issues for large x.

Comment: @slothrop..Thanks I got the point

Answer (score 0):

Initially, for small values of x, the approximation (1 + 1/x)^x is close enough to math.e, so the comparison returns True.
As x increases, the precision limitations start affecting the accuracy of the approximation, causing the comparison to return False.
The oscillation between True and False occurs as the precision limitations continue to influence the result.

Answer (score 0):

whats happens is that you are adding a big number 1  to a small number 1/10**20. Math on a computer is done with fixed precession consider the calculation with  1.000 + 0.00001 with 4 digit precision. It will be rounded to 1 and you calumniation will break.

```
 import math
 e = lambda x: (1+(1/x))**x
 for x in range(1, 20):
...     print( e(10**x))
... 
2.5937424601000023
2.7048138294215285
2.7169239322355936
2.7181459268249255
2.7182682371922975
2.7182804690957534
2.7182816941320818
2.7182817983473577
2.7182820520115603
2.7182820532347876
2.71828205335711
2.7185234960372378
2.716110034086901
2.716110034087023
3.035035206549262
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
```